# Close Jquery dialog on ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

EDIT - I was improperly targeting the dialog. The original code works.

I would like to close a jqueryui dialog on .ajax success.

I have an .ajax method that calls the following when complete...

```
function reserved(d) {
        $(".itemdetail").dialog("close");
}
```

This produces the following error...

> cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'close'

I've researched and haven't found a suitable solution.

Comment: This generally means .itemdetail never had $(".itemdetail").dialog(); called on it in order to initialize it. Are you sure the dialog is open? If so are there multiple .itemdetail elements where one may not have a dialog associated with it?

Comment: The dialog open, so yes, I can see it. I start with a clean page (refreshed), click the element that opens the dialog, click the element that sends the ajax request, then I receive the error on callback.

Comment: Is there more than one .itemdetail on the page?

Comment: do you have a fiddle or some markup of the modal dialog?

Comment: I was improperly targeting the dialog. The original code works. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is initialized and open and then do the certain action.

```
function reserved(d) {
        if($(".itemdetail").hasClass('ui-dialog-content') && $(".itemdetail").dialog( "isOpen" ))
              $(".itemdetail").dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: no - its not initialized. not sure how to handle that though. the dialog is displaying on screen.

Comment: I was improperly targeting the dialog. The original code works. Thanks for your help.